# Old Mac Pro: Windows? GPUs?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, mac-pro, efi

I recently got an old Mac Pro 1,1 for free, and was wondering what's necessary to get it running Windows. I know that you needed Boot Camp before Windows 7, because it didn't support the EFI, but would I need to install MacOS in order to do Boot Camp to do Windows 10? It only officially supports up to Lion because it is 32-bit, and I no longer have a Mac to create an installation disk with.

It also didn't come with a GPU, and I hear that aftermarket GPUs aren't supported by the EFI, so you don't get the boot screen, but once the OS is booted they work. I have a 290X Lightning, do I need to get an old Apple-supported GPU in order to install the OS?